# Thread with call to the databse taking too long causing null pointer

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, hibernate, thread-priority

I have an init method that makes a call to the databse.  The idea here is that when the user comes to the application the init method checks the users credentials by the following:

```
         void initMethod() {
            /** Some setup stuff **/
            hbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            buildBean();
            hbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            user_level = permissionCheck(username);
        }
       /** Later on in file **/
        void login_the_user() {
         /****
         The problem happens here user_level is null because it seems to execute
         faster than the database call.  
         ****/
          if (someArray.contains(user_level)) {
            / ** Do stuff **/
          }
          else { /** Do stuff **/ }
       }
```

It first populates the user bean and then checks the users permissions.  The problem that I am having is that when I run this application normally I get a NullPointerException, but if I run it in debug (I put a break point around here) it works fine.  I believe this is due to the fact that these database calls are run on a different thread which takes more time, and is still null by the time the application uses the data.  So my question is what is the best way to go about this so that the application is able to process these methods before actually using them?

I have tried doing Thread.sleep(1000), but this seems very sloppy and works half the time.

Stack trace below when run normally:

```
.... Long list of database calls getting all the information ....
    Jan 16, 2014 9:43:55 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
    SEVERE: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PatchmgmtUI.permission(PatchmgmtUI.java:331)
        at PatchmgmtUI.access$3(PatchmgmtUI.java:328)
        at PatchmgmtUI$1.beforeViewChange(PatchmgmtUI.java:154)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:592)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:550)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:523)
        at PatchmgmtUI.loginUser(PatchmgmtUI.java:270)
        at PatchmgmtUI.access$0(PatchmgmtUI.java:247)
        at PatchmgmtUI$1.beforeViewChange(PatchmgmtUI.java:148)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:592)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:550)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:523)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:534)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getBrowserDetailsUI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2468)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBrowserDetailsRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2362)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:325)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Jan 16, 2014 9:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Patchmgmtproject Application] in context with path [/PatchMgmtProject] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PatchmgmtUI.permission(PatchmgmtUI.java:331)
        at PatchmgmtUI.access$3(PatchmgmtUI.java:328)
        at PatchmgmtUI$1.beforeViewChange(PatchmgmtUI.java:154)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:592)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:550)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:523)
        at PatchmgmtUI.loginUser(PatchmgmtUI.java:270)
        at PatchmgmtUI.access$0(PatchmgmtUI.java:247)
        at PatchmgmtUI$1.beforeViewChange(PatchmgmtUI.java:148)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:592)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:550)
        at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:523)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:534)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getBrowserDetailsUI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2468)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBrowserDetailsRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2362)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:325)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: how about showing us a stack trace?

Comment: Just added the end of the stack trace where the errors happen, before this there is a list of database calls querying the database.

Comment: why are you running the database operations in a different thread?

Comment: I wrote this application without taking any consideration to threads, so I did not intentionally run the database on a different thread.  So instead of making a method call I should do the operations instead (in place of the methods)?

Comment: method calls do not happen in separate threads.

Comment: when and where is the init method called?  is this a servlet init method?

Comment: Yes this is a web application and the init is the first thing that is called, after the init is called (everything is setup) a viewChangeListener is called and before the view changes it checks the users credentials and sees if he has access to the page

Comment: that would seem to imply everything happens in the same thread, in which case you shouldn't be having timing issues.